# "Conflict power between pins" with a voltage regulator

Tags: kicad

I've built a simple adjustable voltage regulator, but running the ERC shows two errors:

The first one claims that PIN1 is not being driven (it's connected to GND through a resistor; the label is connected to a power pin, connecting the label directly without a resistor fixes the error). I can "fix" the warning with a PWR_FLAG.

The other problem is that the LM1117 family parts have a hidden 4 pin hidden below the 2 pin, both marked as "Power output", and this makes the ERC show an error of "ErrType(5): Conflict problem between pins. Severity: error. Pin 4 of U2 is connected to pin 2 of U2".

[image: Simple vreg]

Is it possible to fix this error?

Comment: You can configure one of the resistor pins as an output to supress the error. You can edit the schematic symbol for the regulator to explicitly show the duplicate pins.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The first one is a problem with the component. Adjustable regulators should not have the reference pin marked as `power_in`.

The second one is a [known limitation](https://bugs.launchpad.net/kicad/+bug/1469525), you can mark the hidden pin as `power_in` in the component as a workaround.

Comment: Good answer.  Also, note that ERC shouldn't flag the second issue if both pin 4 and pin 2 have the same label ("VO" in this case)